# Preview thumbnail for video html5 without poster? Angular

Tags: javascript, html, angular

Very important i don't have a img in api. I need to set preview thumbnail in video.

```
      <video style="object-fit: contain;" width="100%" height="100%" controls preload="metadata"
        [poster]="indexOfSelectedExercise.exercise?.fullVideoUrl" loop>
        <source [src]="indexOfSelectedExercise.exercise?.fullVideoUrl" type="video/mp4" />
      </video>
```

fullVideoUrl: "https://www.url.com/images/Screen Recording 2020-12-01 at 19.01.52.mov"

this is example of url

Comment: If you don’t _have_ an image, then don’t specify `poster`, that does not make sense.

Comment: I know, i need solution without img..

Comment: Then I guess you can only set `preload` to `auto`, hope that the browser starts loading the video, and will use the first frame to present a “preview” once it is available.

Comment: Yes it is anwear which i need :) How to vote up for you?

Comment: Added an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don’t *have* an image, then don’t specify `poster`, that does not make sense. (This expects an image format, so just giving it your video file URL, is pointless.)

You can only set `preload` to `auto` then, hope that the browser starts loading the video, and will use the first frame to present a preview once it is available.

(That this might come with traffic/bandwidth and maybe even performance issues, if this was used for large videos, or multiple videos on a page, should be clear.)